# Is it possible to run an Automator workflow when a program exits?

Tags: macos, automator

Some programs for macOS have annoying background processes that doesn't terminate when I quit the program. Is there some way I can run an Automator workflow, which ends that process, as soon as I quit the program?

Edit: Adobe provides an uninstaller for AGMService to permanently remove it, bypassing part of this problem.

Comment: What are some of these programs?  You could create your own background application that registers for NSWorkspace notifications, but you would need to know what these background processes are.

Comment: @red_menace Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator. The background process is AGMService.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on red_menace's comment, you can create a background app that will wait for a notification from NSWorkspace that Photoshop or Illustrator have quit, which will then quit the AGMService. copy the following code into Script Editor (double-check the localized names for Illustrator and Photoshop, though I think I have them right):

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions

property NSWorkspace : class "NSWorkspace"

on run
    set workSp to NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace()
    set notifCent to workSp's notificationCenter()
    tell notifCent to addObserver:me selector:"someAppHasTerminated:" |name|:"NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification" object:(missing value)
end run

on idle
    -- we don't use the idle loop, so tell the system let the app sleep. this comes out of idle once an hour
    return 3600
end idle

on someAppHasTerminated:notif
    set termedApp to (notif's userInfo's valueForKey:"NSWorkspaceApplicationKey")
    set termedAppName to (termedApp's localizedName) as text
    -- I'm guessing at the localized names for Photoshop and Illustrator. you may need to alter these
    if termedAppName is "Adobe Photoshop" or termedAppName is "Adobe Illustrator" then
        -- close the service here
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "AGMService"
                if its accepts high level events is true then
                    tell application "AGMService" to quit
                else
                    do shell script "killall AGMService"
                end if
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
end someAppHasTerminated:
```

Save it as an application, with the 'Stay open after run handler' box checked:

[image]

Then add it to your startup items so it runs whenever you log in. Then whenever you quit Illustrator or photoshop, it should force AGMService to quit as well. (I don't know if that will cause problems if you quit one while the other is still open).

If you want to make it a hidden background app — one that doesn't show up in the dock or the visible program list — right-click on the applet's icon, choose 'Show Package Contents', then navigate down till you find the 'info.plist' file. Open that file in a plain-text editor (like TextWrangler, or TextEdit in plain-text mode), and edit in the following key-value pair:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Save that, close the file and the package, and the application will run invisibly.